# How to use pandas replace using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe and would like to replace some of the entries based on a regular expression match.  Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
dfl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

          A         B         C         D
0  0.995647 -0.507860  0.246656  0.400589
1 -0.149536 -0.485617 -0.132031  0.214816
2 -0.730974 -0.932630  0.625197  1.887758
3  2.812800  0.329197  0.233513  0.140899
4 -1.897268  0.072307  0.790148  0.096455
```

Now let's convert all the entries to be strings.

```
dfl = dfl.astype(str)
```

Now I would like to replace every number that contains `40`, say, with the word `boat` say.

I tried:

```
dfl = dfl.replace(r'.*40.*', "boat")
```

but this doesn't modify `dfl` at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `regex=True`

```
dfl = dfl.replace('.*40.*', 'boat', regex=True)
```

Details

```
In [278]: dfl
Out[278]:
                 A                 B                C                D
0  -0.389710060851    0.864059364935   0.499405126285   0.457617711403
1   0.136417007517  -0.0650312534859  0.0745132664561    2.02466341236
2   0.842889708053   -0.370605269504  -0.626932398518  0.0440612725966
3  -0.403271275281    -1.37477622923  -0.499721883883   -1.55997893498
4    3.39420415568    0.152915014005   0.205876128883  -0.644183954321

In [279]: dfl = dfl.replace('.*40.*', 'boat', regex=True)

In [280]: dfl
Out[280]:
                 A                 B                C                D
0  -0.389710060851              boat             boat             boat
1   0.136417007517  -0.0650312534859  0.0745132664561    2.02466341236
2   0.842889708053   -0.370605269504  -0.626932398518             boat
3             boat    -1.37477622923  -0.499721883883   -1.55997893498
4    3.39420415568              boat   0.205876128883  -0.644183954321
```